# Rspec isolation testing for model that builds another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following Rails model:

```
class Factory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :widget
  def build_widget!
    widget = widgets.build
    widget.verify!  # does stuff, could raise exception depending outcome of third party api calls, etc.
    widget.save!
  end   
end
```

I have the following Rspec test set up:

```
RSpec.describe Factory, type: :model do
  describe '#build_widget!' do
  let(:factory) { create(:factory) }

  it 'creates a new widget' do
    expect(factory.widgets.count).to eq 0
    factory.build_new_widget!
    expect(factory.widgets.count).to eq 1
  end
end
```

A few problems with this that I'm struggling with:

1) How do I isolate the Factory test so I'm not relying on the outcome of widget.verify! (which I have covered under a separate spec for the Widget model).  Because this method is hard coded inside the method, I'm struggling with how to set up a proper mock or double.

2) Is testing factory.widgets.count the best approach?  It seems a little hackish, but I'm not sure how to properly set up the expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use [RSpec Mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) before expectations:

```
before(:each) do
  allow_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:verify!).and_return(true)
end
```

2) Would be better to track the changes in the object:

```
RSpec.describe Factory, type: :model do
  describe '#build_widget!' do
    before(:each) do
      allow_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:verify!).and_return(true)
    end

    let(:factory) { create(:factory) }

    it 'creates a new widget' do
      expect do
        factory.build_widget!
      end.to change { factory.widgets.count }.from(0).to(1)
    end
  end
end
```